# How to create Hibernate mapping for the following scenario

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

How to create Hibernate mapping for the following scenario. 
I have three tables, `Users`, `Systems`  and `System Assign`.
There are three types of user -- Normal user, super user and admin.

`Users` Table has five columns -- user-ID , userName, password, email id and userType. userType will decide whether a user is super user or admin or normal user.

`Systems` table have some column but the most important is `systemsID` which will be used for mapping.

I have created one table `System Assign` to assign a system to a user with two columns user-ID and system_id (or it can be corrected if required). Also created these two as the foreign key of respective table.

The conditions of mapping are :

1. a user can have one or more system id on his name.
2. a system id can be assign to one or more users.
3. when a system_assign record is deleted from the UI it should only break the link between the user and system but user and system should be in database.

Also I have to make some database changes like this:

- If a super user creates a user , this user will be under him
- if a super user creates a system, system will be under him.
- if a user is deleted then system should come under super user now.

I need to know how to create hibernate classes for this senario

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SYSTEM_ASSIGN")
public class SAssign implements Serializable {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1945028654484806943L;
    @Id
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "USERSSO")
    private Users user;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "SYSTEMID")
    private Systems system;
    public Users getUser() {
        return user;
    }
    public void setUser(Users user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
    public Systems getSystem() {
        return system;
    }
    public void setSystem(Systems system) {
        this.system = system;
    }
}
```

Comment: I can use on hibernate side. but how to manage on database side for this situation. I can do whatever code changes required, just want to run this application

Comment: I have tried creating a class for system_assign giving oneToOne mapping but getting error in saving the object as ORA-01722: invalid number. I will share my class as well

Comment: I have pasted the class

Comment: sure, just give an example i will follow the same to code.

Comment: I think you need to use `@ManyToOne` instead of `@OneToOne` in the `SAssign`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use a list of `Role` instead of `userType` and the `@ManyToMany` association for user and roles. Join tables for the `@ManyToMany` association will be created by Hibernate. You don't need to use persistent classes for it.

Classes with the mapping: [usersystem](https://github.com/v-ladynev/hibernate-experimental/tree/master/src/test/java/com/github/experimental/usersystem)

A test for mapping: [UserSystemTest.java](https://github.com/v-ladynev/hibernate-experimental/blob/master/src/test/java/com/github/experimental/usersystem/UserSystemTest.java)

```
public enum RoleEnum {

    ADMIN, USER, SUPER_USER

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "roles")
public class Role {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "f_pid")
    private Long pid;

    @Column(name = "f_role")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private RoleEnum role;

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "systems")
public class SomeSystem {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "f_pid")
    private Long pid;

    @Column(name = "f_name")
    private String name;

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "f_pid")
    private Long pid;

    @Column(name = "f_user_name")
    private String userName;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_roles", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "fk_user") },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "fk_role") })
    private List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<Role>();

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "system_assign", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "fk_user") },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "fk_system") })
    private List<SomeSystem> systems = new ArrayList<SomeSystem>();

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :) I will analyse and do the same in my app

Comment: @shrish You are welcome. Probably, you will need to rework it, because of it is just a template.